# Discord JS v13 Get Status of Specific User

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For the bot I'm writing I am trying to get the current status of the user that started an Interaction. This is my code, which seems perfectly fine according to the discord.js docs.

```js
console.log(interaction.member.presence)
```

When running this, it outputs null.

[image]

Why is this happening? I've seen some people use fetching but I can't seem to implement that into my app.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled the `presence` intents on the Discord Developer Dashboard and also "offline" users or users who have set their status to offline don't have any presence data, so it returns `null`

Comment: @node_modules right and don't forget to add ```Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES``` intent to your intents on the main file.

Comment: @node_modules what intent on the dashboard?

Comment: @RevelCarlbergWest the "Presence Intent"

Comment: @MrMythical Yeah I wasn't able to find it before.